# How to serialize to XmlWriter using YAXLib

Tags: c#, xmlwriter, yaxlib

I'm trying to use [YAXLib](http://yaxlib.codeplex.com/) to serialize an object. If I serialize directly to a `string` it works fine, but if I try to serialize to an [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) I get an empty xml.

This is a sample class declaration (nothing weird, right?):

```
public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Population { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I'm doing to serialize it:

```
/* Object to serialize */
var city = new City() { Name = "Montevideo", Population = 1500000 };

var serializer = new YAXSerializer(typeof(City));

/* Serialize to XmlWriter */
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter);
serializer.Serialize(city, xmlWriter);

var result1 = stringWriter.ToString(); // result1 is ""

/* Serialize to String */
var result2 = serializer.Serialize(city); // result2 is "<City>...</City>"
```

I need to use the XmlWriter approach because I want to control several aspects of the resulting xml through [XmlWriterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (omit xml declaration, avoid indentation, control new line handling, ...).

**Anyone had successfully serialized to XmlWriter using YAXLib? What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call to `xmlWriter.Flush()` may solve your problem, as it did on my own testing:

```
serializer.Serialize(city, xmlWriter);
xmlWriter.Flush();
```

Comment: Worked. Note that when using the framework's XmlSerializer there's no need to call Flush(). I would like that to be noted in YAXLib documentation.